# Remove a table row but keep the CSS alternate rows format

Tags: jquery, css

So I have a table that has an alternating format for rows (let's say grey and white). I'm deleting a row with the `tr.remove()` jquery function, and of course the css of the rows over/under it will not change, and they will keep their odd/even styles. Basically:

```
Before Deletion         After Deletion

grey                    grey
white                   white
grey                    white
white                   grey
grey
```

Is there any way to quickly force the table to "refresh" the styles? Or do I have to apply them manually using jquery?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This answer is not working as you want.

Comment: Sorry bud, but it is. Wait, in fact I'm not sorry, but grateful =)

Comment: Again see answer and compare with questions. what is missing in both ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So do the styling with CSS instead of using odd/even classes/ hardcoding values.

```js
document.querySelector("tbody").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var td = e.target,
        tr = td.parentNode;
        tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
    
});
```

```css
    tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #FFF;
    }
    
    tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>2</td></tr>
    <tr><td>3</td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td></tr>
    <tr><td>5</td></tr>
    <tr><td>6</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Singh and what browser are you using that it is not working? Demo is just a demo, CSS is all that really matters here.  I did not make the JS portion older IE friendly. Working fine for me in Chrome and Firefox when you click on the numbers.

Comment: I am using firefox latest version

Answer (score 0):

Just utilize `:nth-child(even of :not([hidden]))`. This selector ensures that striping is consistently updated across the entire table.

```js
const hideBtns = document.querySelectorAll("[data-hide-btn]")

hideBtns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    btn.closest("tr").classList.add("hidden")
  })
})
```

```css
table {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 80%;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

table tr:nth-child(even of :not(.hidden)) {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

table th {
  padding-top: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 12px;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #04AA6D;
  color: white;
}

tr.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Company</th>
      <th>Contact</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td><button data-hide-btn>
        Hide
      </button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```